# Detect URL change with dynamic value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect a URL change but the URL has a dynamic value after the hash, for example: `http://myurl/#!/contact/179593927`.

I was able to make the below work but on `http://myurl/#!/contact/` ONLY, but not on `http://myurl/#!/contact/123456789`.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
 if (location.hash === '#!/contact/') {
    $('.controls-bar-1').appendTo('.contact-mod');
    $('.controls-bar-2').appendTo('.contact-mod');
  }
});
```

Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: That should work.

Comment: Yes it works but only to #!/contact/ NOT to #!/contact/123456 hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're checking the *exact* value of the URL fragment. If you want to check if the `/contact` part exists regardless of whether a value is provided or not you could use `indexOf()` to check the start of the fragment only, like this:

```
if (location.hash.indexOf('#!/contact/') === 0) {
  $('.controls-bar-1, .controls-bar-2').appendTo('.contact-mod');
}
```